# Get Modified Fields in RowPersisted Event

Tags: acumatica

In RowPersisted event. Is there a way to know which fields were updated ? I have a customization in my RowPersisted event. But I only want to execute it if certain field(s) were actually modified. At the moment the event is firing unnecessarily as it reacts every time its saved.

TIA

**UPDATE**

Just to add. My customization has got nothing to do with the field values nor overriding the saving itself. I'm just using the RowPersisted event to kick off my customization.

Comment: To compare changes you can use your current row and call cache.GetOriginal(currentRow) where cache is a PXCache object. This gives you the unmodified row for which you can see which fields changed. But as the answer mentioned you should really do this in the Persist call before calling base.I think GetOriginal is a newer call maybe added in 18R1 so might not be available in all versions - just FYI

Comment: Thanks @Brendan. Cache.GetOriginal seems what I'm looking for. You can make it an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: I posted as an answer but might want to update the overall question too if you are just looking for the indicator to modified values vs something specific in RowPersisted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to compare the current row with any changes to the row with unchanged values (as it was from last persist) you can use a cache instance and call GetOriginal.

For example using an extension on sales order to check to see if the order qty or order total changed...

```
[PXOverride]
public virtual void Persist(Action del)
{
    // Current object with any changed values
    var salesOrder = Base.Document.Current;

    // Unchanged object as it was set from the last save/persist
    var unchangedSalesOrder = Base.Document.Cache.GetOriginal(salesOrder);

    if (!Base.Document.Cache.ObjectsEqual<SOOrder.orderQty, SOOrder.curyOrderTotal>(salesOrder, unchangedSalesOrder))
    {
        PXTrace.WriteInformation("My values changed");
    }

    del?.Invoke();
}
```

**Edit**: I think at some point the GetOriginal was not publicly accessible. Not sure which version but if you cannot find this call it could be you are on an older version of Acumatica where this call cannot be used.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the description of the RowPersisted event from [https://help-2018r2.acumatica.com](https://help-2018r2.acumatica.com/Help?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=ac686a56-ea6d-5ece-1063-a2842fb9aaa0)

> public delegate void PXRowPersisted(PXCache sender, PXRowPersistedEventArgs e )
>
> **Parameters**
>   **sender** (**Required**). The cache object that raised the event
>   **e** (**Required**). The instance of the PXRowPersistedEventArgs type that holds data for the >RowPersisted event
>
> The RowPersisted event is triggered in the process of committing changes to the database for every data record whose status is Inserted, Updated, or Deleted. The RowPersisted event is triggered twice:
>
> - When the data record has been committed to the database and the status of the transaction scope (indicated in the e.TranStatus field) is Open.
> - When the status of the transaction scope has changed to Completed, indicating successful committing, or Aborted, indicating that a database error has occurred and changes to the database have been dropped.

The `e` parameter has the only `Row` property which is the current modified record.
You can check your condition on the `e.Row` and execute your code.

You **should not** use `PXRowPersisted` event for modifying values on the Completed transaction. If you need to modify values before/after save the best practice is to override `Persist` and use `PXTransactionScope` and invocation of the baseMethod, see example below:

```
[PXOverride]
public void Persist(Action baseMethod)
{
    using(PXTransactionScope sc = new PXTransactionScope())
    {
        //... do your code here
        baseMethod?.Invoke();
        //... or here 
        sc.Complete();
    }
}
```

**UPDATED**

Ideally, you should follow the rules below:

- if you want to update the values of other fields of your record during the update of some fields then you should use the corresponding `PXFieldUpdated` event handler.
- If you want to prevent saving of the record depending on some conditions of the field values of your record you should you `PXRowPersisting` event handler.
- If you want to update DAC/Table of other maintenance/entry you should do it in the `Persist` method.

Comment: Good advice, modifying values after saving is a very bad anti-pattern. Also I see a lot of people using Persist when events like FieldUpdated/RowPersisting would be more appropriate.

Comment: @HB_ACUMATICA I have updated the answer for that cases

Comment: @SamvelPetrosov, thanks for the advice. But I have no intention to change the field values nor get in the way of the saving the data. I've updated my post to reflect that. Having said that, going back to the original question. How can I get the modified fields in Persist even as per your suggestion ?

Comment: You could manually cache the objects using slots and manually compare the current records with the cached records. That's what Acumatica does but it doesn't keep the history of changes after the FieldUpdated events are consumed.